# Scene Builder Editor displaying weird characters

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

[image: Scene Builder weird characters]

I just installed Scene Builder and my editor looks like this. Can't read anything. I assume somehow I am missing the font the editor tries to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in case anyone encounters this problem. I quickly realized this is not a Scene Builder but a general JavaFX problem. Somehow my Segoe UI font was corrupted or something. I un-/reinstalled it and the characters are displayed normally now.

Comment: How did you un-/reinstalled it? through regedit?

Comment: I think he is talking about the font, seems that he reinstalled the font Segoe UI.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same I downloaded and reinstalled Segoe UI at https://freefontsfamily.com/segoe-ui-font-free/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and just resolved it a few moments ago. Originally, I was running an older version of the JavaFX SDK (version 11) and as soon as I upgraded to version 16 and added this line

```
(xmlns="javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="javafx.com/fxml/1")
```

in my .fxml file, everything became okay.

The strange characters and symbols no longer show when I run the scene, but they are still visible in the Intellij Scene Builder environment. That's okay though, since I can create my scenes in the formal Scene Builder application and simply import them in.