# JavaFX Arabic letters are not displayed at all

Tags: java, macos, javafx, encoding, arabic-support

I have the following FXML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TableView layoutX="54.0" layoutY="136.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="495.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="الرصيد" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ملاحظات" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="دائن" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="مدين" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="التاريخ" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

File encoding is UTF-8 as mentioned above. When I run my project it displays like this:
[image]

Why is it displayed like that? what is wrong? FYI I am using MacOS

Comment: Writing `encoding="UTF-8"` in the XML prolog does not automatically make the file a UTF-8 file.  From a terminal window, run `file /path/to/myapp.fxml`.  That will tell you whether the file is in fact UTF-8.

Comment: @VGR this is the output from terminal ```mainPage.fxml: XML 1.0 document text, Unicode text, UTF-8 text```

Comment: No issue on my end other than you `FXML` missing `<Label>`.

Comment: What version of JavaFX and OS X are you using? Some versions of JavaFX had issues rendering text in MacOS.  Since it works for SedJ601, it may well be that a JavaFX library upgrade could fix your issue.  Try the latest stable version (21.0.1) if you aren't using that already.  Also use JDK 21, because ([starting in JDK 18](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400)) UTF-8 was made the default encoding for the JDK, which simplifies some encoding issues.

Comment: Related: [Why JavaFX application and scene builder is showing garbled text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747171/why-javafx-application-and-scene-builder-is-showing-garbled-text) Where it seems similar issues were resolved for some users by either removing then reinstalling a font (Segoe UI) or upgrading to JavaFX 17+.

Comment: @trashgod Arabic is one of the Preferred Languages in System Settings > General > Language and Region

Comment: @jewelsea I am using JavaFx version 17.0.6. MacOS version Ventura 13.4. JDK version 11. I will try installing JDK 21 and update here. In terms of the related link, I can actually see the correct text on SceneBuilder. It's just when I render

Comment: The issue in the link wasn't actually specific to SceneBuilder, it was specific to a version of JavaFX or installed fonts, so could replicate outside of SceneBuilder.  SceneBuilder ships with its own version of JavaFX and the JDK.  It is possible that the version of JavaFX and the JDK that ships with the version of SceneBuilder you are using works to display correctly, but the version of software you are using when you run your application does not.  You can find information about what version of JavaFX and the JDK is being used in SceneBuilder by checking the about box in the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was in the JDK version not the JavaFX version nor the MacOS version. I was using JavaFX 17.0.6 and JDK 11, which caused the issue. When I updated my JDK to version 21. It worked just fine as shown below:
[image]

Thanks to @jewelsea who suggested I update my JDK.

Comment: Note for those stuck on Java 17 or older: It may be possible to fix this by specifying the charset of the `FXMLLoader` to `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. Or possibly by using `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` to set the system property.